# Redirecting all old URLs in same domain

Tags: redirects, url

I'm relaunching a new site on a current domain, currently there are hundreds of URLs.

With the relaunch, all of the content will have new URLs and there will be no need for the old URLs.

I need to redirect all the old ones to the new URLs like for like.

It will take forever to redirect one by one using htaccess.

I don't mind if all the old URLs redirect to the new homepage just as long they're not 404 but would prefer like for like redirects.

What are my options?

Comment: the portion after domain is going to stay same? i.e. the url folder/structure? like foo.com/jazz to bar.com/jazz?

Comment: No same domain name

Comment: Yes, but I am asking about the par AFTER domain name, like jazz in my above example..?

Comment: Totally new URLS: "With the relaunch, all of the content will have new URLs and there will be no need for the old URLs.

I need to redirect all the old ones to the new URLs like for like."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but redirecting like to like is the only way that you will be able to keep your SEO in tact. So, your 3 options are:

1. [301 redirects from all old pages to the home page](https://moz.com/blog/save-your-website-with-redirects) and face the music that your site may encounter some form of automated negative seo algorithm by Google or Bing.
2. You use `404` or `410` statuses and lose any SEO that those pages gained over the months or years. This can reduce domain authorithy and rankings on other pages.
3. You want your SEO kepted in tact and face the music that you need to spend several hours remapping old urls to new urls.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I knew it had to something like that. With redirecting all to homepage, is it possible to be selective? What about new URLs won't they also redirect?

Comment: You can leave some as 404 and be selective on the ones that you know rank well and have links to. Other than that you either accept some 404's or you 301 from old to new. Do not redirect to the homepage unless the homepage is revelant.

Comment: i thought you could redirect foo.com/jizz to bar.com/jizz with some .htaccess regex, if that is what OP meant..

Comment: @SimonHayter I guess I'll have manually just redirect all.

Comment: Just to add, if you "301 redirect from all old pages to the home page" then these are likely to be seen as soft-404s by Google.